# best meathod to lock onto a cdma signal?

Tags: signal-detection, demodulation

I've been looking at 2 different methods to acquire a known prn code in a CDMA signal. The first trys Xor prn code chip to I sign data. Then average the result over a time period to determine the data bit. I have not had reliable success with this method. The second which I am going to try performs a real multiply of a the code chip and the sign then adds or subtracts the I data magnitude value over a time span. 
Is one method known to be more reliable than the other? I'm typing on phone so I can't post any coding right now. If it would help I can update this question later.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CDMA signals typically have a pilot that is sent along with the data.  This pilot is a known chip sequence that is transmitter over and over again.  Receivers can use the pilot to lock onto the signal by correlating the received signal with the expected pilot.

The autocorrelation is typically done by FFT'ing the received signal, multiplying it by the FFT'ed expected pilot, and IFFT'ing the result.  This is done both for computational efficiency and because the circular correlation that you get with FFT's is actually helpful in this case because the pilot is repeated.  Thus you should be able to "catch" the pilot no matter which phase it starts at in your captured signal.

Once you have locked onto the pilot you know the signal's phase and it should be pretty straightforward at that point to despread the signal and recover the data, providing you know the data's spreading sequence.

Comment: I realize that using an FFT to correlate may well be the best and is by far the quickest way to get the prn phase estimate to start, I'm trying to implement this in an FPGA. So ideally I would like to use a threshhold value to determine if a code lock is present. I'm thinking the second method using the magnatude will produce a wider spread in summed value between lock and not locked than the sign only way. I'm just not sure.

Comment: You can do FFT's and IFFT's in FPGA's.  I have done the approach that I described in an FPGA.

Comment: I'll have to look into how to go about implementing that. Currently I am using a Cyclone 4 development board kit so my single search/tracking channel uses just under half the Logic Elements on the chip. I am searching the old fashioned way, rotating by chip delay the full prn code in 1000 frequency shifts to account for +/- 5 KHz carrier doppler shift. I am using the boards leds as my only diagnostic. Right now I can tell when I have a near lock as a led flashes every summed 1000 matching IF sign / code sign matches. So far switching over and staying in tracking has eluded me.

Comment: Algorithm experiments in FPGA's are very time consuming and frustrating.  I suggest capturing snapshots of the signal into a file and then working out the algorithm experiments in Matlab, Octave, or NumPy.

Comment: I've figured out that I cannot seem to lock on the pilot code. Finally bought an osciliscope. I've set up a second fpga board to act as a transmitter and currently have it just outputting a PRN code. My receiver is now just trying to match the code. I did get a lock once after just hitting the fpga board reset and rebooting the start sequence but it seems to have been a fluke. I can't tell if my delay code is actual functioning correctly or not.

Comment: 'CODE'    //code delay control based on clock cycles delay 50MHz
  if(!lock)
  begin
   if(count_slewCycles < delay_slewCycles) codeEnable <= 1'b0;
   else codeEnable <= 1'b1;
   count_slewCycles <= count_slewCycles + 28'd1;
  end
  else if(lock) codeEnable <= 1'b1;'CODE' the coder should not advance unless the codeEnable is high

Comment: Again, I highly recommend taking a snapshot of the received signal and then playing with it on a computer using Matlab, Octave, or NumPy.

Comment: Thanks for the replys Jim. I was hoping to not have to learn another programming language like needed for matlab but I may need to just take the time to do so. I know right now I have a working delay to create a sliding correlator and according to one of the leds on the board I get a "lock" consisting of bit matches above a threshhold once per second. I have also managed to stop the oscilliscope at just the right millis a few times to see the codes line up. Problem is it wont lock to the code chips. I may just need to tweek my tracking equation. I just wish there was a sliding code example?